# Updating a many to many relation - Entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am using entity framework in order to save a many to many relationship. 
Obviously parts of the relationship already excists in the DB and it gives me a duplicate KEY error.

How do I make entity-framework overwrite on Insert ?

My error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__PaymentL__3214EC07CE1C6DCF'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PaymentLine'. The duplicate key value is (47c78fb5-b536-4920-b7e6-c925e9879aee).
```

One of my tables looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PaymentLine](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,           ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to implement something like an "insert or update" in a related collection. This is not directly possible.

If you need to do something like this using EF, you need to check if the relation exists in the DB by loading the related entity. If it exists, leave as is, and save changes. If it doesn't exist, create it, and save changes.

For example, is you have a relation of many to many between items and colors, and you want to insert or update a color to its Colors collection, you need to check if the color is already present:

```
 var itemId = 12; // The item
 var colorId = 18; // The color to insert or update
 Color color = ctx.Items.Single(i => i.ItemId == itemId)
                  .Colors.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ColorId == colorId);
```

Then if `color` is `null`, you know you have to insert the color:

```
 Item.Find(itemId).Colors.Add(newColor); // before SaveChanges()
```

If it's not null, you know you have to update it (if the color itself has changed), or leave as is (if you're only interested in the relation).